# MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork empty with Apple Music

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmediaitem, mpmediaplayercontroller

I can't retrieve MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork while playing a song from Apple Music with iOS 8.4

I've try to read image of `nowPlayingItem`

`(lldb) po [[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork]`


`<MPConcreteMediaItemArtwork: 0x174478940>`

But the object returned is empty:

`(lldb) p (CGRect)[[[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] bounds]`


`(CGRect) $2 = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 0, height = 0))`

And obviously the returned image is always nil

there's another way to get the `nowPlayingItem` `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork`image?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I just ran up against it myself.

Comment: Same here, any updates? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour happens when you are streaming songs from Apple Music which are not saved to the users library.

I've filed a bug report for this, and I think you should do too  You can dupe rdar://25413082 if you want.

The best workaround is to use the iTunes API (or similar) to retrieve the album Art although this won't give perfect results 100% of the time.

Comment: Can you post a link to the radar? Can't seem to find it.

Comment: @FotiDim Where are you looking? Radars are not public.

Comment: I thought you were referring to http://openradar.me. Was there any update on the issue?

Comment: Talked to some of the engineers at WWDC. They’re looking into it but it’s more complicated than just returning the image.